# Abrir en nueva ventana con Ajax

Tags: ajax

Tengo un código en ajax que no lo he creado yo, y no se como modificarlo para que el enlace se abra en una nueva pestaña.

> Nota: Es un botón, que se activa a los 5 segundos de espera, y esto es
>   únicamente una parte del código que compone su programación.

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json', // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
        type: 'POST', // he HTTP method to use for the request
        url: goForm.attr('action'),
        data: goForm.serialize(), // Data to be sent to the server.
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            submitButton.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('a.get-link').text('<?= __('Getting link...') ?>');
        },
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            //console.log( result );
            if (result.url) {
                //console.log( result.message + ' - ' + result.url );
                $('a.get-link').attr('href', result.url).removeClass('disabled').text('<?= __('Get Link') ?>');
                //submitButton.text( 'Redirecting...' );
                //goForm.replaceWith( '<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript: return false;">Redirecting...</button>' );
            } else {
                alert(result.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el enlace se abra en una nueva ventana debes usar [window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json', // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
        type: 'POST', // he HTTP method to use for the request
        url: goForm.attr('action'),
        data: goForm.serialize(), // Data to be sent to the server.
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            submitButton.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('a.get-link').text('<?= __('Getting link...') ?>');
        },
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            //console.log( result );
            if (result.url) {
                //console.log( result.message + ' - ' + result.url );
                window.open(result.url, "_blank");
                //submitButton.text( 'Redirecting...' );
                //goForm.replaceWith( '<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript: return false;">Redirecting...</button>' );
            } else {
                alert(result.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir la url en otra ventana usa:

```
window.open(result.url, "_blank");
```

Comment: Te sugiero revisar [answer], **esta pregunta parece ser similar a la que respondió anteriormente Camilo**, @JoseAntonioDominguez te sugiero, agregar más información a tu respuesta!